Remote Control/Remote Access in React-Vite-Electron in Zoom Video SDK
I have a scenario where I want Remote Control/Remote Access in React-Vite-Electron app. I am using Zoom Video SDK for it, but I am unable to figure out how to implement it and find relevant resources. Any leads would be appreciated!

Developers zoom and Electron are good resources to learn. Keep an eye on the Zoom Developer Forum to stay updated on any changes to the roadmap

I have like spent a lot of time on it, there isn't any proper guide or hint for it. All I just got to know that they were working on it.

"Learning Electron: Building Cross-Platform Desktop Apps" by Cezar Tataru" is definitely great book for electron but  it doesn't directly address Zoom SDK integration. .Official GitHub(already mentioned) repository for Zoom's Electron SDK. It includes example code and usage documentation that can be a great starting point for your learning.
